# Extracting matrix indices in R by row

Tags: r, matrix, vector

R language stacks the matrix values column wise.

```
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    7   12   17    3
[2,]    3    8   13   18    4
[3,]    4    9   14   19    5
[4,]    5   10   15   20    6
[5,]    6   11   16    2    7

>A[4]
[1] 5
```

is there a way this can be numbered row wise?
I mean that A[4]=17

Comment: You need row, column index i.e. `A[1,4]` (if I understand what you meant)

Comment: You could transpose your matrix via `t()` ("flip it over the diagonal"). Is that what you want?

Comment: The answer is no, in `R` matrices are vectors with a `dim` attribute. For instance, try `x <- 1:10; dim(x) <- c(5, 2); x` to see what I mean. This matrix `x` is just a vector folded **column** wise.

Comment: @akrun: Yes I can do that but I was looking if I can get a single value.

Comment: Could you define your own matrix class, inheriting from the `matrix` class, but overloading `[` to behave differently?